# Targeting parents elements next sibling in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

Forgive my ignorance, I'll try to be as clear as possible. I'm trying to modify an existing JS function that adds a class to a parent element. I would like to modify it to add the same class to a sibling of the parent, in this case the aside '.footnote-right-col'.

I have tried a good number of ways but this is beyond me. I'm not sure if I need to create a new function and call it separately, or if I can simply add a new variable to this function. I presume the way I would target the parent is via getParent.nextSibling

As is JS

```
  open: function (el) {
      this.footnote.el = getParent(el, '.footnote-container')
      var popover = this.footnote.popover()

      this.footnote.el.classList.add('is-open')
      this.sizeFootnote()

      popover.classList.remove('is-hidden')

      this.positionFootnote()
      popover.classList.add('is-visible')
      window.addEventListener("resize", self.resize.bind(self))
    },
```

Rendered HTML

```
<div class="footnote-container open-down">
   <button class="footnote-button" title="view footnote #1">...</button>
   <aside class="footnote-popover is-hidden">...</aside>
</div>
<aside class="footnote-right-col is-hidden">...</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.footnote.el.nextElementSibling` Should get you `.footnote-right-col` element if I am understanding how you set things. If `this.footnote.el` is the `<div class="footnote-container open-down">` element then my answer works. Once you have that div you can just call the `.nextElementSibling`

EDIT:
ok so cool if `this.footnote.el` is the button then simply do this:
`this.footnote.el.parentElement.nextElementSibling` and you should have it!

So to add the class:
`this.footnote.el.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add('is-open')`

Comment: Thanks ekr990011, I think I may have put you wrong. `this.footnote.el` is the `.footnote-button`. I will edit my original question to make it more clear.

Comment: Think I got an answer for you hopefully

Comment: Thanks ekr990011. In the end I was wrong in my first response to your solution. Your first explanation is right. Adding `this.footnote.el.nextElementSibling` to the function worked. Many thanks, and for the speedy response :)